# BigInteger.Parse works incorrectly

Tags: .net, math, biginteger

It's very strange for me, but you can try yourself this short code:

```
var num1 = BigInteger.Parse("1e+9999", NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
var num2 = BigInteger.Parse("1e+9998", NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
var div = num1 / num2; // is 1, but must be 10
var eq = num1 == num2; // true, but must be false
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the documented range of dotnet BigInteger?

Comment: Unlimited! Perhaps, size of RAM.

Answer (score 5):

When parsing a `BigInteger` in exponential form, the .NET FX code limits the exponent to 1000. If a larger exponent than that is found, an exponent of `9999` (!!) is substituted instead. See [FormatProvider.Number.cs, from line 495](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/Common/src/System/Globalization/FormatProvider.Number.cs#L495). You can see for yourself:

```
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse("1e+1000", NumberStyles.AllowExponent).ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse("1e+1001", NumberStyles.AllowExponent).ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

> 1.000000E+1000
>
> 1.000000E+9999

Even though this is not a limit of `BigInteger` itself, just a limit of the parser:

```
Console.WriteLine((BigInteger.Parse("1e+1000", NumberStyles.AllowExponent) * 10).ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

> 1.000000E+1001

I’d call such a surprising and incoherent behavior an obvious bug, but the behavior is caused by an explicitly added piece of code and I am unable to find an exact specification regarding `BigInteger` limits apart from [“arbitrarily large” and “whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds”](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Can you suggest some workaround? What can I do for initialization BigInteger with value e.g. 10^100000 ?

Comment: @TimeCoder you could also figure out what the hexadecimal value of `10^100000` is and pass in the appropriate value to the constructor that [accepts a `byte[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is like a paradox, "figuring out the value of `10^100000`" without BigInteger class.

Comment: In other words, I can translate 10^N (N ~ hundreds of thousands) in polynom of 2 and fill byte[] array. Looks good.

Comment: I would say the easiest way would be `BigInteger.Pow(new BigInteger(10), 100000)`.

Comment: I would just go with the `Pow` solution. It is very fast to calculate.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Works perfect!